# Nested API JSON Result not converting into columns in dataframe Pandas

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe

I am getting a API response something like this:

```
"candles": [
  [
    "2021-04-29T09:15:00",
    1488.85,
    1503.65,
    1461,
    1471.65,
    12002248
  ],
  [
    "2021-04-30T09:15:00",
    1450,
    1450,
    1407.65,
    1412.9,
    17538562
  ]
]
```

When I am trying to convert this to a dataframe it is taking everything in single column.

I am using df = pd.DataFrame(historical_data,)

I want to give them some column name along with data getting columnized for the nested ones not the top level.

Comment: Can you add your expected output to the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading in, transform the list in each row to a series

```
cols = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['candles'], index=cols), axis=1)
```